# How to arrange the flushleft and flushright beside each other?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%% Header Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ } 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\headerpic}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (current page header area.north west) 
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{#1}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}%Opening Statement

    \begin{titlepage}
        \headerpic{logo}



        \begin{center}
            \textsc {\LARGE Master Thesis\\
            \ in\\
        \ M.Sc. Mechanical Enginnnering \\}

            \vspace{2cm}

            \textsc{\LARGE Development of Method for FEA \\
                \ of the x xxxx\\}

            \vspace{2cm}
            \textsc{\Large Shubham xxxx \\
            \ Matriculation Number xxxx \\}     
        \end{center}
    \vspace{2cm}
    \begin{flushright}
        \textsc{ Second Examiner \\
        \ Mr. xxxx \\
    \ Construction Department \\
\ xxxx forschungs und entwicklungs GmbH \\
\ Rebenring xx \\
\ xxxxx Braunschweig \\}
    \end{flushright}
            \begin{flushleft}
            \textsc{ Supervising Professor (First Examiner) \\
                \ Prof.xxxxx  \\
                \ Mechanical and Process Engineering \\
                \ xxx University of applied Sciences \\
                \ Muensterstraße xx\\
                \  Duesseldorf \\}
        \end{flushleft}


    \end{titlepage}
```

As shown in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Please don't public personal data on the Internet, change them with fake ones...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain better what you want to get? Only throwing a code at us without explaining what it should do or what you want to get makes it hard to help you ...

Answer (score 2):

A `\Longunderstack` is ideal for these sorts of things.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%% Header Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{ \thepage\ } 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\headerpic}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (current page header area.north west) 
    {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{#1}}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}%Opening Statement

    \begin{titlepage}
        \headerpic{example-image}



        \begin{center}
            \textsc {\LARGE Master Thesis\\
            \ in\\
        \ M.Sc. Mechanical Enginnnering \\}

            \vspace{2cm}

            \textsc{\LARGE Development of Method for FEA \\
                \ of the Trans-Confabulator \\}

            \vspace{2cm}
            \textsc{\Large Sam Doe \\
            \ Matriculation Number 12345 \\}       
        \end{center}
    \vspace{2cm}
{\scshape\Longunderstack[l]{
            Supervising Professor (First Examiner) \\
                \ Prof. Dr.-Ing. habil. John Doe \\
                \ Mechanical and Process Engineering \\
                \ XYZ University of applied Sciences \\
                \ Muensterstraße 000 \\
                \ 40476 Duesseldorf \\
                \ Tel: xxx-xxxxx \\
            \ john.doe@duesseldorf.de}
\hfill
\Longunderstack[l]{Second Examiner \\
        \ Ms. Jane Doe \\
    \ Construction Department \\
\ Blah forschungs und entwicklungs GmbH \\
\ Rebenring 00 \\
\ 38106 Braunschweig \\
\ Tel: xxx-xxxxxxx \\
\ jane.doe@hofer.de}
}
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]